# Loop through list of form elements array to get or fetch the elements we need or want to keep

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

This is my current code, I'm looking for a more efficient way of writing it.

Need something like looping through each variable with a foreach or adding them all to an array somehow, without me having to re-write every variable name.

```
$formValues = $form_state->getValues();    

$relocation = $formValues['relocation'];
$europe = $formValues['europe'];
$twoyears = $formValues['twoyears'];
$realestate = $formValues['realestate'];
$nominated = $formValues['check_nominated_by'];
$nom_comp = $formValues['nom_company'];
$nom_contact = $formValues['nom_contact'];
$nom_email = $formValues['nom_email'];
$contact1 = $formValues['contact1'];
$position1 = $formValues['contact_position1'];
$email1 = $formValues['email1'];
$contact2 = $formValues['contact2'];
$position2 = $formValues['contact2'];
$email2 = $formValues['contact2'];
$contact3 = $formValues['contact3'];
$position3 = $formValues['contact3'];
$email3 = $formValues['contact3'];


tempstore = array();
$tempstore['relocation'] = $relocation;
$tempstore['europe'] = $europe;
$tempstore['twoyears'] = $twoyears;
$tempstore['realestate'] = $realestate;
$tempstore['membertype'] = $membertype;
$tempstore['nominated_by'] = '';
// All other fields need to be in this array too
// But there are a lot of unwanted fields in the $formValues
$_SESSION['sessionName']['formName'] = $tempstore;
```

Comment: *Need something like looping through each variable with a foreach* - There is your answer or do you just want the code for it?

Comment: How about `$_SESSION['sessionName']['formName'] = $formValues`?

Comment: I don't know how to write the code to do this, don't know which functions or logic to use. There are a lot of other unwanted variables in $formValues

Comment: Loop through them with an array with keys you'd like to keep.

Comment: Serious question, random downvotes again, this is why I stopped using this website ...

Comment: `// All other fields need to be in this array too` You should clarify what you need exactly.

Comment: They're not random, the question is unfortunately  rather poor.

Comment: You already have all the data in `$formValues`, why do you create all those variables?

Comment: // But there are a lot of unwanted fields in the $formValues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you know the keys you'd like to keep you can do the following:

```
<?php

/** The keys you want to keep... **/
$keys_to_keep = [

];

/** Will be used to store values for saving to $_SESSION. **/
$temp_array = [];

/** Loop through the keys/values. **/
foreach ($formValues as $key => $value) {
    /** The correct key i.e. the key you'd like to save. **/
    if (in_array($key, $keys_to_keep)) {
        /** What you wish to do... **/
        $temp_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}


$_SESSION['sessionName']['formName'] = $temp_array;
?>
```

What is happening is that you are looping through your `$formValues` and getting *both* the keys and values of each pair in the array.

Then an check is being done against your `$keys_to_keep` to see if the current element is the one you wish to keep, if it is then you save it in to `$temp_array`.

**Reading Material**

[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

[`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: @PascalClaes please read through the **Reading Material** and in the future clarify your question clearly from the start.

Comment: Accept timer was still running. I know how foreach and in_array work, this is just something I would have never thought of myself ...

Comment: You don't even need a `foreach`, `in_array()` and all the other stuff. `$t = $formValues; unset($t['key1'], $t['key2']/*, and so on */); $_SESSION['sessionName']['formName'] = $t; unset($t);`. It's shorter and more clear.

Comment: Unless there are 50 unwanted keys in $formValues?

Answer (score -1):

You can use variable variables and a foreach.

```
Foreach($formValues as $key => $var){
    $$key = $var;
}

Echo $relocation ."\n" . $europe;
```

https://3v4l.org/QeLjp

Edit I see now that your array variable keys are not always the same as the variable name you want.
In that case you can't use the method above.
In that case you need to use list() = array.

```
List($relocation, $europe) = $formValues;
// The list variables have to be in correct order I just took the first two for demo purpose.
```

Comment: That's what `extract()` does. But how would that help the OP?

Comment: @jeroen didn't know of extract. But yes that is true. See my edit, I didn't see the variables didn't match the array items.

Comment: extract() doesn't really help me. Variable names don't matter